# Testing Bluebird Promises with Nodejs Vows (BDD)

Tags: node.js, promise, bluebird, vows

I'm having trouble with how to properly structure a test for my Promise-returning API with Vows, e.g.

```
topic:function() { return myfunc() { /* returns a Bluebird Promise */ } },
'this should keep its promise':function(topic) {
    var myfunc = topic;
    myfunc()
        .then(function(result) {
            assert(false);
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
            assert(false);
        })
        .done();
}
```

My vow never fails. This is my first attempt at using vows to test promises. Hoping someone familiar with this will lend a hand.

In advance, thank you.

Enrique

Comment: Would you be interested in a solution that uses a different bdd library?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum I would be interested in trying an alternative; thank you. I tried Bluebird's nodeify and the vow continued to succeed when it should not have. Thanks for the responses.

Comment: In that case I suggest using Mocha in place of vows. See my answer for how.

Answer (score 2):

Since unlike libraries like Mocha - Vows does not yet have support for testing promises, we use its regular asynchronous test format that takes callbacks:

```
topic:function() { return myfunc() { /* returns a Bluebird Promise */ } },
    'this should keep its promise':function(topic) {
    var myfunc = topic;
    myfunc() // call nodeify to turn a promise to a nodeback, we can chain here
        .nodeify(this.callback); // note the this.callback here
}
```

Here is how it would look with mocha:

```
describe("Promises", function(){
   it("topics", function(){
       return myfunc(); // chain here, a rejected promise fails the test.
   });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The following example is using a when js style promise with vows. You should be able to adapt it to whatever flavor of promise you are using. The key points are:

1) Make sure you call this.callback when your promise resolves. I assign 'this' to a variable in the example below to make sure it is properly available when the promise resolves.

2) Call this.callback *(see below how this is done with the variable)* with an err object and your result. If you just call it with your result, vows will interpret it as an error.

```
  vows.describe('myTests')
  .addBatch({
  'myTopic': {
    topic: function() {
      var vow = this;
      simpleWhenPromise()
        .then(function (result) {
          vow.callback(null, result);
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
          vow.callback(result, null);
        });
    },
    'myTest 1': function(err, result) {
      // Test your result
    }
  },
})
```

Comment: A late thank-you for this, Mr. Gauer. I'll give this a shot sometime soon.